# Check only specified key is down

Tags: .net, wpf

I can check whether key is down by `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` method. But how can I check specified key is only key which is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get the current keyboard state and work out what keys are pressed, but its a bit messy and uses the user32.dll. Have a look at the answer to this one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752761/1232571

Answer (score 0):

dependant on which key you want to check do something like this

```
if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    //do something
```

Comment: If Key.LeftCtrl is down, it doesn't mean it is the only key which is down

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to want to do something only if that one key is pressed try something like

```
if(!Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)) return;
```

That will throw them out of the function if the key pressed isn't what is required.

Comment: But if there were multiple buttons pressed including LeftCtrl e.g. LeftCtrl and RightCtrl it wouldn't throw you out of the function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can count the number of KeyDown vs KeyUp? If the counter is 1 and it's the key you want....