#  How to detect if any key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

How can I detect if any keyboard key is currently being pressed? I'm not interested in what the key is, I just want to know if any key is still pressed down.

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.ANYKEY??)
{

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<Key> KeysDown()
{
    foreach (Key key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)))
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
            yield return key;
    }
}
```

you could then do:

```
if(KeysDown().Any()) //...
```

Comment: `if (key != Key.None && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))` because `Key.None` is not valid and raises an exception

Answer (score 6):

If you want to detect key pressed only in our application (when your WPF window is activated) add `KeyDown` like below:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown);
}

void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You pressed a keyboard key.");
}
```

If you want to detect when a key is pressed even your WPF window is not active is a little harder but posibile. I recomend [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) (Defines a system-wide hot key) and [`UnregisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327.aspx) from Windows API. Try using these in C# from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerhotkey.html) or these tutorials:

- [Global Hotkeys: Register a hotkey that is triggered even when form isn't focused.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/)
- [Simple steps to enable Hotkey and ShortcutInput user control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5914/Simple-steps-to-enable-Hotkey-and-ShortcutInput-us)

Thse is a sample in [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/87d66b1c-330c-42fe-8a40-81f82012575c).

You will use [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx).
I Hope that I was clear and you will understand my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum values.

```
public static bool IsAnyKeyDown()
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key));

    foreach (var v in values)
        if (((Key)v) != Key.None && Keyboard.IsKeyDown((Key)v)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer here...get the set of all the keystates at once using `GetKeyboardState()`:

- [Detect if any key is pressed in C# (not A, B, but any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752494/detect-if-any-key-is-pressed-in-c-sharp-not-a-b-but-any)

The above is checking the live state of the keyboard.

If you rely on hooking events up to the KeyDown/KeyUp events to track the state of the keyboard...then this may not be so accurate.

That's becuase you are relying on the message pumping to process and dispatch those KeyDown/KeyUp messages....they may be delivered after the real keyboard state has changed again.

Also because when your bit of code that is interested in the keyboard state is running (usually on the UI thread)...the KeyDown or KeyUp can't interrupt you...as they are dispatched on the UI thread too....that's why using `GetKeyBoardState()` or the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` should be used.

(the above is assuming you want and care about the live state)