# Detect all the Key Pressed in keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

is there a way to detect all the key pressed in keydown event of the form? 
For example im currently pressing CRTL + Alt + A can i get all the keys in keydown event? i need to get all the keys to create my own hot keys in my currently developing application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752494/detect-if-any-key-is-pressed-in-c-sharp-not-a-b-but-any

Comment: Hi i didnt get all the pressed key by applying this to my project any idea?

Comment: you want to know what keys are presseD?

Comment: Yes is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find which keys are pressed, you could do this,

```
     if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt) // Is Alt key pressed
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Key pressed"); 
            }
       }
```

Comment: it not getting all the keys that i pressed appreciate the effort

Comment: @bRaNdOn Try my modified answer

Answer (score 1):

You can check for all keys in event arguments

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt && e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about all keys, to create a hotkeys combination, so chekcing every property in 'e' isn't a good idea.