# WPF KeyDown and Keyup events

Tags: wpf, events, keydown

Hi when I do in one of my user controls in a WPF application,

```
this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(ControlViewer_KeyUp);
```

or

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ControlViewer_KeyUp);
```

or

```
this.AddHandler(Window.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(ControlViewer_KeyUp), true);
```

I can never get the key events to fire when pusing a key on the keyboard.

Would anyone know why?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347724/how-can-i-capture-keydown-event-on-a-wpf-page-or-usercontrol-object

Answer (score 6):

the event is probably being handled before you can get to it, if any handlers mark the `KeyEventArgs e.Handled = true;` you wont get the notification, try using the `PreviewKeyDown` or `PreviewKeyUp` events and see if you have more luck.