# Can't implement movement in Snake

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make Snake, but have a problem with the controls. I made an application with few pages and can't add KeyDown to the page where the game starts. KeyDown works well when I add it to PageSwitcher.xaml

Here is my code:

https://github.com/Zibann/LastTry

Comment: That are two questions. Please post them seperatly

Comment: ok, only one problem left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Explorer -> Changes -> then look for untracked files, right click and select add. Sometimes (I'm not sure when) the new files you add are not tracked by default.

[image]

Comment: @KrzysztofUrbańczyk I would like tou help you with the other question but I dont understand it

Comment: I don't know how add control to arrows, make method Window_KeyDown in Singleplayer.xaml.cs and add KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" in Singleplayer.xaml but this dosen't work.

Comment: ok i find answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347724/how-can-i-capture-keydown-event-on-a-wpf-page-or-usercontrol-object