# Dialog window `KeyDown` Event Handler not hitting (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, key-events

I have a `KeyDown` event handler (created by Visual Studio) for my dialog to close the window:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

When I'm in the program and press the `Escape` key, the dialog goes to the back of the main screen instead of closing it.  I put a break point in at the function, and it never hits.

Has this happened to anyone before?  Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Does it hit your breakpoint if you press a key that isn't Escape?

Comment: Yes.  I just put in a test to see if it would read the `Space` bar.  Worked fine.  It's not my `Escape` key either.  I did this for like 20 other dialogs yesterday.  It's literally just for this one...

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere besides the code you've shown. Did you check the designer.cs file for any stray references to your form?

Comment: It's not a WinForm....  I wish it was that easy.  Xml

Comment: `#line 8 "..\..\..\HydAnalysis.xaml"
            ((AutoSPRINKforRevit.Hydraulics.HydAnalysis)(target)).KeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(this.Window_KeyDown);`

Comment: Have you ever figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/980518/37899

Basically, if your dialog is completely empty and there isn't a focused control, the KeyDown and Up events will not be raised. For some reason they only get raised when there's at least one focusable control in the window and it's focused.